# Get set of Items of Arraylist containing HashMaps and put in different HashMap Java

Tags: java

Good day, I have an Arraylist of HashMaps with the structure

```
 [{key1, value1}, {key2, value2}...{keyn, valuen}] , [{key1, value1}, {key2, value2}...{keyn, valuen}] .
```

So evidently, my ArrayList has a size of 2. Now i am trying to get the first set on Item in the ArrayList and put it in a HashMap.. i try this,

```
HashMap<String,String> infoMap  = new HashMap<String,String>();
    infoMap.putAll(arraylist.get(0));
```

but it seems to be adding everything inside the arraylist and not the first item. What could i be doing wrong or am i mis-understanding the putAll() method.

**update:** 
this is how i populated the Arraylist.

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> parseJSONObject(JSONObject json) throws JSONException{
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String date = null;
        String value = null;

        JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("datasets");

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
            JSONArray array2 = array.getJSONArray(i);
            Log.d(TAG, "array2 size is " + array2.length());


            for(int j = 0; j < array2.length(); j++){


            JSONObject jobj = array2.getJSONObject(j);
            date = jobj.getString("Date");
            value = jobj.getString("Value");
               map.put(date, value);
            }

            arrayList.add(map);
        }

        return arrayList;
    }
```

Comment: The code looks fine. Have you tried with a small example?

Comment: Can you show the code for List fully. As the code is fine.

Comment: The code above will add all the entries in HashMap1.  However, maybe you have accidentally added all the entries to HashMap1 somehow already?  We would need to see more code to find a bug I think.

Comment: @Ted think you are right. I added all the entries to the same HashMap before i put it in an ArrayList. Would like to have different Hashmaps but don't know if it is a good idea to create them in the for-loop

Comment: @Fedy2 Sorry for the rather late response. i have added the code to how i populated my ArrayList

Comment: @manuelJ: of course you must create it inside the for loop. Otherwise, you will have a single map instead of one for each element of the JSON array.

Comment: But since your eventual goal is to merge them together into infoMap anyway, you can just use the map HashMap as your final result, and don't bother returning an ArrayList of HashMaps but just return the HashMap and it would look cleaner.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for the information. But won't it be resource intensive as if its a bit array, then i have to keep initializing for each HashMap. Wondering if there would be a cleaner way for this. But Nonetheless, Thanks once again.

Comment: @Ted Thanks, will take that advice.

Comment: Start by making your program correct before trying to making it fast. A VM can create tens of millions of HashMaps in a single second. A fast program that doesn't work is useless compared to a program which works fine and takes some nanoseconds more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) in the comment, you have to initialize the Map inside the loop, otherwise you will put all the elements in the same map.
Here the correct snippet:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
  HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
```